# How do I get and set model data that's nested deep in Backbone?

Tags: backbone.js

I have this model and I want to update the team value when I gather the correct info on a form submit but I'm not sure how to the specific team. I know in backbone I can use the `model` to get `teams` but I'm not sure how to then go from teams into the correct team using the code attribute?

I've tried:
// My new team to replace team in code EFU"

```
    var newTeam: {
      "id": "POS-876",
      "name: "Swansea City"
    }

var teams = this.model.get('teams');
var selectedTeam = teams.get('EFU'); // I know this is wrong
selectedTeam.set('team', newTeam);
```

I'm not sure how I target the correct team then update the team details?

---

**Model**

```
{
            "id": "4V6",
            "name": "Premier League",
            "teams": [{
                    "code": "EFU",
                    "team": {
                            "id": "POS-1",
                            "name": "Manchester United"
                    }
            }, {
                    "code": "BMD",
                    "team": {
                            "id": "POS-223",
                            "name": "Chelsea"
                    }
            }]
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Model is a bit confusing. Why is it wrapped in array brackets? And why are you `get`ting `'exchanges'` instead of `'teams'`? And should perhaps `teams` be a collection instead of a simple array?

But in any case, to find the specific team, you can use Underscore.

```
var selectedTeam = _.findWhere(teams, {code: 'EFU'});
```

Comment: Apologies, I had copied that model from the collection and left the square brackets in by accident!

Comment: How do I then set the selected team with the new data? I'm trying this.model.set(selectedTeam.team, newTeam); but with no success

Comment: Your selected team isn't a backbone model; it's just a plain old JavaScript object: `selectedTeam.team = newTeam;` But it sounds like you might want to spend some time with a basic Backbone tutorial. Code School has some particularly good ones.

Comment: Ah ok!! Yeah I will spend some time on there, I've kind of just been dipping in and out of things as I go along! One more question, if I'm updating the model like this with plain old objects, when it come to save the model will these changes be picked up ok?

Comment: Yes, saving the model will update all of it's child objects.

Comment: Another question if you don't mind, you say about making a collection out of the team attributes, how can I specifically make a collection that handles just the teams?